# htmx: hx-target-error fails when hx-target defined (django python)

Tags: python, django, htmx, response-targets, hx-target

I am using the htmx extension "response-targets" via "hx-ext" in a python django project.

**The Problem**

"hx-target-error" will not work when "hx-target" is also defined, but works when it is the only *target*.

**Environment**

htmx 1.9.10, response-targets 1.9.10, python 3.12, django 5.0.1

**Example html**:

```
<div hx-ext="response-targets">
    <button
        hx-get={% ur "appname:endpoint" %}
        hx-target-error="#id-fail"
        hx-target="#id-success"
        type="submit"
     >
         Press Me!
     </button>
</div>
```

**hx-target**

I have tried with various other types of targets such as "next td", "next span", etc. All of them produce a valid target value "request.htmx.target" in the endpoint defined in views.py.

**hx-target-error**

I have also tried various alternatives supported in response-targets such as "hx-target-*", "hx-target-404", etc with no change in results.

I verified that "response-targets" is installed correctly and being used correctly because when "hx-target" is removed from the "button", then "hx-target-error" works.

**Error generation in views.ph**

```
@login_required
def endpoint(request)
    return HttpResponseNotFound("Not found 404")
```

**Logs**

```
Bad Request: /testbed/endpoint/
127.0.0.1 - [27/Feb/2024] "GET /testbed/endpoint/ HTTP/1.1" 404
```

**response-targets extension**

https://htmx.org/extensions/response-targets/

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you remove login decorator or remove `type=submit` ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, exact same behavior with either or both of those items removed (login decorator and type=submit).

Comment: I see you're getting "bad request" response in the logs. Does it return any specifc error message? Do you have DEBUG enabled?

Comment: @mariodev - The "Bad Request" is the result of purposefully returning a 404 Not Found HttpResponse from the endpoint function: `return HttpResponseNotFound("Not found 404")`

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. It should return 404 in the logs as well. I'm trying to find the reason for 400 being thrown.. Do you have DEBUG enabled?

Comment: The 400/404 discrepancy is a typo on my part in transferring between my testbed and the pseudo-code for the post. The original has been edited.

Comment: I had the same issue. Then I found this https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/2361  I solved it by moving the extension higher in the div tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved**: The solution is to move the "hx-ext" attribute `<div hx-ext="response-targets">` to a higher encompassing level than any DOM elements referenced by either "hx-target" or "hx-target-error".

In my case, "hx-target-error" pointed to a div 'id' outside of the div containing "hx-ext".

Thank you @guigui42 for suggesting [this solution](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/2361)

**Example incorrect usage**:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div hx-ext="response-targets">
            <button
                hx-get={% url "testbed:rebound" %}
                hx-headers='{"custom": "{{ test.id }}"}'
                hx-target-error="#GET-{{ test.id }}-fail"
                hx-target="#GET-{{ test.id }}-ok"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-primary testbed-btn"
            >
                GET {{ test.msg }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="GET-{{ test.id }}-ok" />
        <span class="text-danger" id="GET-{{ test.id }}-fail" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Example correct usage**:

```
<tr hx-ext="response-targets">
    <td>
        <button
            hx-get={% url "testbed:rebound" %}
            hx-headers='{"custom": "{{ test.id }}"}'
            hx-target-error="#GET-{{ test.id }}-fail"
            hx-target="#GET-{{ test.id }}-ok"
            class="btn btn-sm btn-primary testbed-btn"
        >
            GET {{ test.msg }}
        </button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="GET-{{ test.id }}-ok" />
        <span class="text-danger" id="GET-{{ test.id }}-fail" />
    </td>
</tr>
```